# Metal Evaporation in GFAAS?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Our lab is doing aqua regia digestion of an ore matrix for the determination of Platinum Group Elements (PGE). We're getting white smoke when we run it through a Graphite Furnace assisted Atomic Absorbance Spectroscopy (GFAAS). Smoke forms above 1000 C, so we think it's some metal evaporating. Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give us a little chance to understand your question and [edit] in what those abbreviations mean.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン GFASS relates to Graphite Furnace assisted Atomic Absorption Spectroscopy, i.e. a sample is quickly atomised in a graphite tube.  To ensure the sample won't condense at the inner walls of the tube, often, a L'vov plate is added supporting the sample -- then, if the sample atomizes, the walls of the tube is even hotter than the tube.  And graphite, to mute potential ASS fingerprints by metals.  PGE -- speculating -- may refer to platin group elements (Ru, Rh, Pd; Os, Ir, Pt).

Comment: Martin-マーチン Sorry for the confusion! Thank you for suggesting edits so I can ask questions better next time on this forum. Buttonwood, thank you for clarifying my remarks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not evaporate the metals in question.  The use of aqua regia in the analysis aims to dissolve them, to *form salts*, which in turn are significantly more volatile than the metals or will decompose in the gaseous state.  (Just have a look alone at the *melting points* of the pure metals, which still are considerably lower than the boiling points, too.)

Without further detail about the colour of the "smoke", it remains a speculation that the sample placed on the L'vov plate still *might* have been a bit wet (from the acidic digestion).  If so, it were not good for the instrument, as it may lead to corrosion to metal parts of the housing around the graphite tube.

Comment: In the good old days of wet chemical  analysis ; It was typical to dissolve a sample in acids and then heat it to dryness producing " copious" smoke.

Comment: @blacksmith37 The good-old silicate analysis of concrete/cement and steel samples I learned in France equally consists of crushing the sample with $\ce{NH4Cl}$, than gentle cooking for half an hour or so with concentrated HCl.  Not too seldom that eventually the sample was boiled (Teflon beaker) with aqua regia for quite some time, either.  Well, the hood had to be cleaned anyway from time to time from the inner, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood thank you very much for answering this query of mine! We are planning on switch methods that will involve tellurium precipitation, like how this paper explains [link](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0039-9140(89)80257-7). We think there must be something in the soil matrix that is interfering with our GFAAS method, because even when we did a nitric acid digestion to measure cobalt and palladium levels, white smoke was still emerging. Thanks again for your insight and willingess to answer this question!

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast Interestingly and quite unexpected for me, your reference approaching petrography is indexed by the freely accessible database PubMed (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18964774). As so often, at the side there is the column "similar articles" (here, 251 entries) which might contribute to screen literature further. Good luck!